# Como utilizar uma variável de um função X em uma função Y em Python?

Tags: python, funções, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Sou estudante do primeiro período de Eng. da Computação es estou tendo alguns problemas para entender como conseguiria (se for possível) utilizar a variável de uma função dentro de outra, as duas sendo executadas dentro de uma terceira função.

O problema é simples (e eu já consegui fazê-lo funcionar de forma mais rústica), tenho que criar um programa básico para calcular uma fórmula de Bhaskara e informar delta, raízes, etc. No entanto gostaria de criar uma função para lidar com delta, uma para lidar com as raízes e tudo dentro de uma função Main.

'''

```
def delta_res (a, b, c):
  delta = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
  print("\nDelta é igual a", delta,)

def bhaskara_res (a, b, c):
  if delta < 0:
    print("\nA equação não tem raízes.\n")
  elif delta == 0:
    print("\nA equação tem apenas uma raíz.\n")
    x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
  else:
    print("\nA equação tem duas raízes.\n")
    x1 = (b + delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (b - delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    print("As raízes da equação são",x1 , "e", x2,"\n")

def main (a, b, c):
  if a == 0:
    print("\nSe 'a' é igual a 0, a equação não é de segundo grau.\n")
    return
  delta_res (a, b, c)
  bhaskara_res (a, b, c)

main(a=int(input("Dê um valor para a: ")),
b=int(input("Dê um valor para b: ")),
c=int(input("Dê um valor para c: ")))
```

'''

No entanto, a variável "delta" dentro da função "bhaskara_res" não consegue acessar a variável "delta" dentro de "delta_res".

Como faria para poder resolver esse problema?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Utilize o `return`. Estude sobre funções [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). Na função `delta_res`, por exemplo, bastaria fazer: `return delta`. O valor retornado pela função pode ser acessado na chamada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo link, Felipe!
A princípio realmente tentei o `return` , mas acabei recebendo a resposta **' <' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int '** .
Fiz a tentativa de transformar `delta_res` em um int ( `int(delta)` ), mas recebi **int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'**

Comment: Alguma ideia do que possa ter feito de errado?

Comment: Você precisa chamar a função... O documento que referi mostra como fazer isso, você chegou a ler? Um outro link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functions-in-python-a-beginners-guide/

Comment: O que aconteceu na realidade era que eu estava chamando a função `delta_res` de `main` , quando deveria estar chamando de dentro da função `bhaskara_res` . Coisa simples. Pensei em apagar pergunta pelo julgamento mesmo, mas acho que pode ser útil para outra pessoa sem experiência como eu que precise.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz algumas alterações baseados no que você comentou, para ter acesso ao valor que uma função manipula a melhor forma é fazer essa função retornar esse valor, eu fiz a sua função delta_res retornar o valor de delta e a função bhaskara_res receber mais um valor além de a,b,c (observação: nessa função bhaskara_res a variável c nunca é utilizada então é recomendável remove-la) agora recebem também o valor de delta. E na hora de chamar a função você pode primeiro criar uma variavel para receber o valor de delta e depois colocar essa variavel na função bhaskara_res ou diretamente colocar a função delta_res na função bhaskha_res, no lugar onde deve ficar o delta. Em caso de duvidas é só falar.

```
def delta_res (a, b, c):
  delta = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
  print("\nDelta é igual a", delta,)
  return delta

def bhaskara_res (a, b, c, delta):
  if delta < 0:
    print("\nA equação não tem raízes.\n")
  elif delta == 0:
    print("\nA equação tem apenas uma raíz.\n")
    x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
  else:
    print("\nA equação tem duas raízes.\n")
    x1 = (b + delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (b - delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
    print("As raízes da equação são",x1 , "e", x2,"\n")

def main (a, b, c):
  if a == 0:
    print("\nSe 'a' é igual a 0, a equação não é de segundo grau.\n")
    return

  else:
    #bhaskara_res(a, b, c, delta_res(a,b,c))
    #Você pode usar o código acima ou o código abaixo
    delta = delta_res (a, b, c)
    bhaskara_res (a, b, c, delta)

main(a=int(input("Dê um valor para a: ")),
b=int(input("Dê um valor para b: ")),
c=int(input("Dê um valor para c: ")))
```

Comment: Se o delta é zero, bastaria fazer `-b / (2 * a)` (pois como o delta é zero, a raiz quadrada também é zero, e somar esse zero com `-b` não faz diferença).